# Remove values in a cell found in another cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am wondering if there is a formula, or several, that can remove values within a cell (not delete the cell entirely) that are defined in another cell(s).
Example:
"123 New York St Chicago IL 98765" to be "New York St Chicago IL" by using a formula that looks at the cell with the street # "123" and zip "98765" values and remove it from the cell with the full address. 
Using Text to Columns is not an option at this point because there are no commas separating values, and all addresses are not in similar formats. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide an example spreadsheet? Are you interested in a formula solution or would you use an Apps Script solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`Substitute()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332).  This would need to be a helper cell, as formulas in the worksheet cannot remove/delete data.

Example:

```
       A      B       
1      cat    =Substitute(A$4,A1,"") 'output: The  chased the dog.
2      dog    =Substitute(A$4,A2,"") 'output: The cat chased the .
3
4      The cat chased the dog.
```

If you are looking to actually remove/delete data, you would need VBA, which isn't appropriate for Google-sheets.

Answer (score 0):

in Google Sheets you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A; "\d+"; )))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Or using Textjoin+Filterxml function, of which Textjoin available in Office365

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[.!=0+.]"),0))
```

[image]